# Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth headphone always reconnect in Mono

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04, headphones

I'am new to linux. I'am under Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a bluetooth Headphone (Doqaus Care1). The pairing works fine and the sound is Ok until the headphone goes in power save (if there is no sound/music played, the headphone shuts down).

But when I turn it on, and play music again, it plays it in Mono.

I have to disconnect and reconnect it (in the bluetooth menu) to recover the stereo.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have found a working solution here, https://askubuntu.com/a/1030961/513874 but it seems like a bug...

Answer (score 1):

Go to sound settings, output device section. Your headset should be selected. Below in configuration check if it's headset head unit (HSP/HFP). That is low quality mono. Select the high fidelity playback A2DP Sink. In most cases this should fix it.
In my case it didn't - it said it's in stereo but only left channel played. Bluetooth on linux has awful implementation, so could be anything.
In the end what fixed it for me was command line

```
sudo btmgmt
hs on
```

Good luck!

Edit. Typos.

Comment: Thanks selecting 

> Select the high fidelity playback A2DP Sink. 

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if the suggested solution didn't help):

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

(Solved on Ubuntu 20.04 for Sony WH-CH520)

MDH

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).